# Creating html table without putting empty tds

Tags: html, css, html-table

Sorry to ask this simple question. But I seem not to be able to find some reasonable answer to it.

I want to make a table with 3 columns but all three having different number of data. say, 1st column has only 1 data. 2nd one has 3 and 3rd one has also 3 data. It should look like this:

[image]

is there another way than defining empty `td`s for the first and second `tr` to create empty slots?

Comment: Where would be the `th`’s here (theoretically)? Is the content of one row related? Or is the content of one col related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rowspan`  http://jsfiddle.net/vB2jY/

This will make the `td` cell occupy the number of rows mentioned.

```
<table>
    <tr><td rowspan="4">1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the 1 in the first column is not on the top part, but rather in the middle. i want it to be just in the same line as the first item of second column.

Answer (score 1):

I think a table is best suited only for displaying tabular data, and not complex layouts like what you describe.

Still you can achieve this by using the `rowspan` attribute for the data in the first column, to extend to 3 rows.